# Finding calculate value or collect values tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, calculate-values

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 and I need to use the calculate value tool or collect values tool to in ModelBuilder, but I cannot find those tools.

Do I need to download them from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Accessing Model Only tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/modelbuilder/accessing-model-only-tools.htm):

> There are two ways to access Model Only tools in ModelBuilder: from
>   the Insert menu or from the shortcut menu.